# Doubly linked list can call a function on each node item?

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to create a method on a LinkedList constructor that can takes in a function and call that on each node item. This is what I have so far:

this is my constructor:

```
function LinkedList() {
  this.head = this.tail = null;
}
```

I have a addToTail method that I tested and works:

```
LinkedList.prototype.addToTail = function (item) {
  let newNode = new ListNode(item);

  if (this.tail) {
    this.tail.next = newNode;
    newNode.prev = this.tail;
    this.tail = newNode;
  } else {
    this.head = newNode;
    this.tail = this.head;
  }
  return this; 
};
```

where:

```
function ListNode(item, prev, next) {
  this.item = item;
  this.next = next || null;
  this.prev = prev || null;
}
```

Now I'm trying to call a function on each node item:

```
LinkedList.prototype.forEach = function (iterator) {
  return this.map(iterator (item))
```

Can anyone explain to me why my forEach returns a []? Also i tried console.log(this) and also got []. What would be the best way to approach this? Thank you!

Comment: Show us how you defined `LinkedList.prototype.map`. Since you (incorrectly) forward there, it should be obvious why it returns an array.

Comment: 'item' in iterator(item) will be undefined.

Comment: I was trying to use the Array.prototype.map() method. But I just remembered my linked list isn't an array so I'm now completely lost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, it is not the best solution, however, you can iterate via your linked list and execute the function `func` on each member:

```
LinkedList.prototype.forEach = function (func) {
  let cur = this.head;
  while (cur) {
    func(cur); // Call your function
    cur = cur.next;
  }
};
```

Or, if you want to add a `map` function to your linked list,

```
LinkedList.prototype.map = function (func) {
  let res = [];
  let cur = this.head;
  while (cur) {
    res.push(func(cur)); // Call your function and add the result
    cur = cur.next;
  }
  return res;
};
```

then, you can call:

```
LinkedList.prototype.forEach = function (func) {
  this.map(function (e) { return e; }).forEach(func);
};
```

Comment: If you find this Answer useful, please show it to others by an upvote or solved state. Maybe, someone else has a similar question.

Comment: I gave it an upvote! :) Sorry I'm a student and still very new to stackoverflow

Comment: Thank you. You can upvote answers and you can mark an answer as the answer that fits best to your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!